# Set rounded corners for UILabel

Tags: ios, objective-c, uilabel, uibezierpath, rounded-corners

Is there a way to set cornerRadius for only top-right and bottom-right corner of a UILabel?

I tried the following, but it is not working at all and I didn't get expected output using below code.So please can anyone make correction in my code if required?

```
 UIBezierPath *maskPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:lblCollectPaymentAmount.bounds
                                               byRoundingCorners:(UIRectCornerTopRight | UIRectCornerBottomRight)
                                                     cornerRadii:CGSizeMake(5.0, 5.0)];

CAShapeLayer *maskLayer = [[CAShapeLayer alloc] init];
maskLayer.frame = lblCollectPaymentAmount.bounds;
maskLayer.path = maskPath.CGPath;
lblCollectPaymentAmount.layer.mask = maskLayer;
lblCollectPaymentAmount.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
```

Comment: Your code is working well. Did you check your lalbel background color

Answer (score 4):

Apple has introduced `maskedCorners` property from iOS 11 and above which is very handy.

```
    lbl.clipsToBounds = true
    lbl.layer.cornerRadius = 10
    lbl.layer.maskedCorners = [.layerMinXMinYCorner, .layerMaxXMinYCorner]
    //You can give an array for .layerMinXMinYCorner, .layerMaxXMinYCorner, .layerMinXMaxYCorner and .layerMaxXMaxYCorner to give all corner a radius.
```

You can also declare an IBDesignable class for the label.

```
@IBDesignable
class CornerLable: UILabel {
    @IBInspectable var cornerRadius:CGFloat = 10

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        layer.cornerRadius = cornerRadius
        layer.maskedCorners = [.layerMinXMinYCorner,.layerMaxXMinYCorner, .layerMinXMaxYCorner, .layerMaxXMaxYCorner]
    }
}
```

DON'T FORGET TO GIVE IT `clipsToBounds = true` in storyboard or in code.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

@drashti:

it might help you :

```
    let rectShape = CAShapeLayer()
    rectShape.bounds = self.customView.frame
    rectShape.position = self.customView.center
    rectShape.path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: self.customView.bounds, byRoundingCorners: [.bottomLeft , .bottomRight , .topLeft], cornerRadii: CGSize(width: 20, height: 20)).cgPath

    self.customView.layer.backgroundColor = UIColor.green.cgColor
    //Here I'm masking the textView's layer with rectShape layer
    self.customView.layer.mask = rectShape
```

Comment: in my case customview should be my label Right ? but although its not working.

Comment: @drashti : Yup, here customView is label

Comment: As suggested by @vp2698 Please check by giving a background color to it.

Answer (score 0):

There is appeared `maskedCorners` property in IOS 11.